# How Autoscaling works in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to the AWS ECS. I am trying to understand Tasks and EC2 instances in the context of ECS Autoscaling. I have one Task definition. This means that when the Task is created under a service, there will be one EC2 instance. Suppose if the service needs to be scaled out through autoscaling. What happens in this scenario?. Following are my queries:

1) If I have mentioned 1 EC2 instance in the Cluster setting, what will happen to the autoscaling? Will it create a new EC2 instance?

2) Can autoscaling create two tasks in the same EC2 instance if there is enough free resource in the 1st EC2 instance? If so, What will happen to the port, because now there will be two tasks with the same port mapping.

3) This is not related to the Autoscaling, but if I have two different task definition with the same port name. Does it mean that these tasks will run on two different EC2 instances in the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If I have mentioned 1 EC2 instance in the Cluster setting, what will happen to the autoscaling? Will it create a new EC2 instance?
A)If you have configured ec2-autoscaling and scaling policy. Based on that it will create the new ec2 instance.

2) Can autoscaling create two tasks in the same EC2 instance if there is enough free resource in the 1st EC2 instance? If so, What will happen to the port, because now there will be two tasks with the same port mapping.
A)So In ECS, two task of the same service will not run on the same instance because of the High Availability.

3) This is not related to the Autoscaling, but if I have two different task definition with the same port name. Does it mean that these tasks will run on two different EC2 instances in the cluster?
A) No, if the resource is available it will run on the same or different ec2-instance. Don't worry about the port number as whatever you have defined on task definition that is the container port number and each container run on the same port. So it can be same across task definition.

Comment: point (3).  If I access the EC2 instance URL in a browser and if the port number of both the task definition were 80 then how does the DNS know to which container it should route the request?.  This is the case if the two different tasks are running on the same EC2 instance

Comment: For this, if you are using the ALB/NLB as the frontend for the ECS services, in that case LB will take for that and you can give different path to different services to access that.
Example: service 1 -> task 1 -> /cost
                service 2 -> task 2 -> /product
So you can access via http://<ALB Domain Name>/cost or http://<ALB Domain Name>/product.
This example considering that you have not defined the host port so that any free port which is as per AWS 49153 through 65535 will be mapped to the instance and from there to ALB. But if have defined the host port then you need other ins.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating a bit more on the same containers running on the same host. No, auto-scaling is not going to launch more of the same containers on the same EC2 instance (unless you have more tasks than EC2 instances, and the tasks don't have overlapping ports). If you worry about container ports being the same for copies of the same container then what you can do is to specify dynamic port mapping in your task configuration. Then your containers will receive randomly picked up outbound port from the range of ephemeral ports. You can place those containers into a single target group which can be targeted by Application Load Balancer.

You can run multiple same/different tasks per cluster and even per EC2 instance but the underlying containers can't share the same outbound port. If your instance already runs a container which is listening on port 80, launching another container that would listen on the same port will automatically fail. So the answer to your 3rd question is yes, they will need to run on different instances.